# WPF Get Items From a ListBox as the type of the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, itemtemplate

I have a Listbox as so:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyGui.Controls"
```

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" x:Name="MyDataContainer">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:DataDisplay />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I would like to enumerate through the items from the listbox as objects of type: MyGui.Controls.DataDisplay, as specified in the ItemTemplate. For Example:

```
foreach (var row in MyDataContainer.Items)
    if (row != null)
    {
        var tmp = MyDataContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row);
        if (tmp is ListBoxItem)
        {
            return (tmp as ListBoxItem).PROPERTY_I_WANT as DataDisplay;
        }
     }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, is there a problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to some degree, most often virtualization will thwart efforts to do this for all items. This being the case it is not recommended, if there is *anything* you need to access on a control in the `ItemTemplate` or on the container you should bind it, either in the template itself or the `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: I went for a re-design of my code, as, once I got 3 steps further in I realised there was nothing I could bind to.
This solution did solve my initial problem however.

Comment: @Shane: That sounds like a problem, or did this somehow take out the initial problem?